# ImageView: scale properly above Button

Tags: android, imageview

I'm new to Android and everything went well until now I have to deal with the layout.
What I want is this layout:

Layout how it should be:
[image]
The image should be properly scaled and keep its ratio.

That's why I tried this XML code, but it doesn't work the way I want. The image keeps its ratio but the left and right side are out of the screen when vertical and cut at the top and bottom when horizontal:

Layout how it is:
[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/background">


     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_logo"
        android:layout_weight="2.5" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center">  

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:text="@string/text1"
            android:textSize="40sp" 
        />

          <Button
            android:id="@+id/id2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:text="@string/text2"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/id3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text3" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I googled a lot but just could not find what I was looking for.
Please help!

Comment: Can you provide an approximate picture of what is the situation now and what should it look like ?

Comment: Please share your expected Output Picture,, so that we can figure it out

Comment: I added a picture to the question.

Comment: Can't it just be scaled down if it is too big?

Comment: remove android:layout_weight="2.5"  from image view and check if it is working

Comment: No, it isn't. Then I have to give the image a certain height and either match_parent and wrap_content don't work.

Comment: it looks like `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` is what you are looking for

Comment: @vmironov: Oh my God, THANK YOU SO MUCH! Can I upvote this anyhow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

you have to design 2 layout for you vertical state and horizontal state and put them in two different folder in your android project:

while you put your regular layout in the layout folder you should put the landscape layout in the `layout-land` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to your `ImageView`.

Comment: But it doesn't keep its ratio then.